# Disable submit button in coffeescript

Tags: ruby-on-rails, coffeescript

I have some date validation that I am doing that works well. In addition to displaying an error message when there is an invalid date range I would like to disable/enable the submit button. Here is my coffeescript...

```
jQuery ->
  to_date = null
  from_date = null
  $("#to_date, #from_date").bind "change", ->
    from_date = new Date($('#from_date').val())
    to_date = new Date($('#to_date').val())
    if from_date > to_date
      $("#date_error").text("Error! Not a valid date range")
      $("#submit_button").attr("disabled", true)
    else
      $("#date_error").text("")
```

...and my html when I do view/source...

```
...
  <div id="submit_button">
    <input name="commit" type="submit" value="Create Orientation" />
  </div>
...
```

I know my JS is loading cuz my error message is being displayed, no button disabled. Ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't disable a `div`. You've to disable the actual `input`. So just do this:

```
$("#submit_button input").attr("disabled", true)
```

Comment: "The .prop() method should be used to set disabled and checked instead of the .attr() method." http://api.jquery.com/prop/

Comment: is there a way to change the submit button to "Please wait.." after click?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.preventDefault();`

I didn't try with your code, but you can test this:

```
  $('#submit_button input').click (e) ->
    e.preventDefault()
```